# How to Receive, Modify and Save value from same textbox in MS Access 2010?

Tags: ms-access

Please support.
I've an Access Form with few combo and text boxes. I'm calling information in some text boxes from access tables after selecting value from one of the Combo box. Values are coming correctly but I also need to replace the old information with new one and update the same table again with new information. I tried many VBA codes but Access is giving me error "Reserved Field" every time and close the form automatically.

Can someone please help me here? Let me know what more information you need from my end. I'll be grateful to you. Thank you

Comment: Bind your form to the table, and it will work without code. That's the idea behind Access forms.

Comment: Code may still be used to find existing record requiring update. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html. Otherwise, bind the form as Gustav suggests and use the intrinsic tools to search/sort/filter records.

Comment: Thank you Gustav but the form is already bound to the table. And, I thought that is the reason I'm getting "Reserved field" error as there is one another form bound to the same table? Is my thinking correct?

Answer (score 0):

With out seeing specifically what you are trying to do it is difficult to be sure what you need. What I think you want is to update the test boxes and the desired table fields based on a combo box selection.

If that is your desire you need to bound the text boxes as suggested. Then the VBA code would update the value property of the text box:

if me.controls("comboboxname").value = "a" then
   me.controls("textboxname").value = "A"
Else
    if...   (etc etc)

Or instead of nested ifs you could use case.

Once the form was closed or the record changed the tables would be updated.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. What you suggested is done already. I'm getting the values after selecting the value from combo box. I want to share the picture of my form, how can I do that?

Comment: The error you are getting with your bound fields might be this:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-E33EB3A9-8BAA-4335-9F57-DA237C63EABE